# Pass ArrayList from SurfaceView subclass to Activity

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I'm storing items into an ArrayList when a user is clicking on a SurfaceView which is contained inside my main Activity.

Main Activity XML

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <newProject.SurfaceClass
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/spaceField" />


</LinearLayout>
```

onTouch in SurfaceClass

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

        if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        {
            int touchX = (int)(motionEvent.getX());
            int touchY = (int)(motionEvent.getY());
            Point point = new Point(touchX, touchY);

            mItemsClicked.add(point);

            for (int i = mItems.size()-1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                Item item = listOfItems.get(i);

                inventory.add(item);



            }
            invalidate();

        }
        return false;
    }
```

How would I go about being able to use this inventory ArrayList inside my Main activity, in order words pass that ArrayList so that I'm able to simply click a button from my activity and have that ArrayList console logged for example.

Comment: have you defined your Surface class as a inner class on your Activity Class?

Comment: I have Surface class as it's own class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add a public method in the surface class that returns the list

```
 getMyList()....
```

and in you Mainactivity.. use find view by id to get the object of surface class

```
mySurfaceView= findVi....
```

and then...

```
mySurfaceView.getMyList();
```

Answer (score 0):

A view is in an Activity. Why not create a Global member variable ArrayList in the Activity that your SurfaceView has access to and can populate it and then read that information from the Activity when needed. Using a simple for each loop.